# Pre-image of closed, surjective, continuous map with compact fibres is Lindelöf if its image is

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness, closed-map, lindelof-spaces

I've been trying to prove the following result to no avail:

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a continuous, closed, surjective map with compact fibres (i.e. a perfect map) between two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$. Moreover, suppose that $Y$ is Lindelöf. Prove that $X$ is Lindelöf.

So far, I tried pushing an open cover of $X$ into Y, constructing a countable subcover and pulling that back into $X$, but I was not able to show that this would indeed cover X. I also tried constructing a countable compact cover of the $f^{-1}(\{y\})$. These approaches I also attempted using the map $f^{\ast}(U) = Y/f(X/U)$ and its various nice properties.

A hint would be much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $X$. WLOG we can assume it's closed under finite unions (if we extend the cover by these finite unions, if the larger cover has a countable subcover, so has the original one).

It then follows, by closedness of the map $f$ and compactness of its fibres (or also from your $f^\ast$) that for every $y \in Y$ we can find an open $y \in V_y \subseteq Y$ so that $f^{-1}[V_y] \subseteq U_y$ for some $U_y \in \mathcal{U}$.

Now the $U_y$, corresponding to the countable subcover of the $V_y$ of $Y$, are as needed.

Comment: It always seems obvious when you read someone else's proof...Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lollo231000 it’s a straightforward adaptation of the same fact for compactness.

Comment: And obviously the exact same proof works if Y is countably compact!

Comment: @Lollo231000 Then we need a countable cover of $Y$ so there we need to be subtle. Countable cover of $X$, add the finite unions (still countable) and for each $U \in \mathcal{U}$ that happens to contain a fibre we consider the $f^\ast(U)$'s and then we can go on with that subfamily.